# Full calendar to show all employees appointment colum wise

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

How can i use arshaw's full calendar to show all employees day wise appointment in single calendar column wise.??

On day view i am able to set see all employees appointment but how can i make column for different employees ?

[image]

Comment: I dont think you will be able to do that just using the Fullcalendar API you would have to alter base code to do that.

Comment: m also searching for that

Comment: doing something similar, using events as appointments,
but for one person at a time in month view

Answer (score 0):

[This feature has been suggested](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490), but seems not yet been implemented in FullCalendar v2.1.1. However I found [a fork that implements a "Resource view"](https://github.com/seankenny/fullcalendar). The author of the fork wrote [an article](http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2014/08/11/fullcalendar-with-a-resource-day-view-v2-0-2/) on his blog as well.

There is [a demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/cX9dH8eTjKaddJ0Gpw21/preview) that is based on FullCalendar v2.0.2, however it seems he already started to move on to FullCalendar v2.1 which changed a lot from the previous versions.

The demo code shows that a 'resourceDay' view type is added and you can define resources and assign resources to an event. I think this is very intuitive to use.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'month,agendaWeek,resourceDay'
 },
 defaultView: 'resourceDay',
 resources: [{
   'id': 'resource1',
   'name': 'Resource 1'
 }, {
   'id': 'resource2',
   'name': 'Resource 2'
 },
 events: [{
   title: 'R1-R2: Lunch 12.15-14.45',
   start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 15),
   end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 45),
   allDay: false,
   resources: ['resource1', 'resource2']
 },
 ...
});
```